# WebStorm: Git integration does not sync with terminal git

Tags: git, phpstorm, webstorm

I have a weird issue with WebStorm. I used to use PhpStorm and never had any problem with Git, but I can't figure out how to set up properly WebStorm in that case.

PhpStorm/WebStorm have a convenient way to highlight files that have been modified or added (blue or green titles). However in my case this might be true on the first launch, it then fails as soon as I use git in the terminal to commit. Again, this was working perfectly fine in my former install of PhpStorm, but in this install of WebStorm, it just seems to detect any file I have modified after a commit as a new file.

This impairs me for 2 things:

- I see all edited files as new files (green), regardless if I have then committed any changes to them, so soon enough I have a lot of green highlighted files
- I can't use the convenient function to revert changes by block

I have searched the web and the JB help, but maybe I can't formulate my issue well enough because I can't find anything.

[image: All files remain green even though they are committed already]

I am fairly happy using the command line in my dev process, so I do not want to start using a UI for git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to have fixed the issue:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000118110-Git-commit-no-changes-detected-problem-solved-

But why was it added to the list of ignored files is another question that will remain unanswered.

Comment: Please accept your own answer so that other know your question is resolved.